# Как из геттера вызвать действие? Vuex

Tags: vuex

Слава миру разработки! Не могу найти как из геттера хранилища Vuex вызвать его же действие (action).

Коротко о задаче: необходимо хранить геолокацию пользователя и дать доступ к ней через геттер. Если геолокация неизвестна, она запрашивается у браузера и запоминается время последнего запроса. Геттер, прежде чем вернуть координаты, проверяет время с последнего обновления данных. Если времени прошло много - повторяем запрос к браузеру и обновляем локацию.

Вот мой набросок:

```
const MIN_CHECK_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 2 // Две минуты

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  getters: {
    async getLocation (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) {
      if (!state.location || (new Date() - state.updatedAt) > MIN_CHECK_INTERVAL) {
        // dispatch('defineLocation') <<== МОЙ ВОПРОС
      }
      return state.location
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setLocation (state, location) {
      state.location = location
      state.updatedAt = new Date()
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async defineLocation (state) {
      let location = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (pos) => resolve(pos), (err) => reject(err)
        )
      })
      state.commit('setLocation', location)
    }
  },
  state: {
    location: null,
    updatedAt: null
  }
}
```

Пробовал сделать так:

```
state.dispatch('defineLocation') // dispatch is not a function
rootState.dispatch('location/defineLocation') // dispatch is not a function
```

Возможно, что в геттерах запрещено менять состояние. Но если же нет, то мне хотелось бы узнать как.

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение данной ситуации - это использование действия вместо геттера! Да, это не решение, а путь в обход, но всё же работать будет! Вот как это теперь выглядит:

```
const MIN_CHECK_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 2 // Two minutes

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    location: null,
    updatedAt: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setLocation (state, location) {
      state.location = location
      state.updatedAt = new Date()
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async defineLocation ({ commit }) {
      let location = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (pos) => resolve(pos), (err) => reject(err)
        )
      })
      commit('setLocation', location)
    },
    async getLocation ({ state, dispatch }) {
      if (!state.location || (new Date() - state.updatedAt) > MIN_CHECK_INTERVAL) {
        await dispatch('defineLocation')
      }
      return state.location
    }
  }
}
```